# Set of points with a given distance form a set

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

I have a set of points S, and a subset of it S1. I'd like to find a set of points S2, such that any point in S2 has a neighbour in S1 with a distance <= r.
Further, there are no guarantees about the structure of S1 (ex. its alpha complex might not be convex, or even connected).

Any help? I'm really stumped and the brute force approach <strike>doesn't really work well</strike> breaks horribly. Since the set S2 will be used for sampling, I'd accept an (randomized) approximation as well (it does need to be more precise than a computing the centroid of S1 and selecting points in the radius r of it ;) )

Edit: The points are located in R^3, equipped with euclidean metric

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question has been flagged as offtopic, and marked as a candidate for migration to a sister site, http://math.stackexchange.com/ for example.

Comment: @AlexisPigeon okay... how do I go about migrating it? Or is it an automatic process? Although, personally I believe that this less of an mathematics question and really a programming topic.

Comment: Should we assume S1 and S2 are disjoint subsets of S?

Comment: For each point in S-{S1}, find the minimum distance from {points in S1}. Then sort the points according to their distances and keep adding the points to S2 while the distance <= r.

Comment: Not enough information. What is the size of S? What is the property of S2? Do you want largest such set, if not any one of the points having <= r distance from S1 can be S2.

Comment: Sounds like the [Fixed-radius near neighbors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-radius_near_neighbors) problem.

Comment: Are these points in 2d euclidean space?  3d?  Or what?

Comment: @user1990169 Yeah, sorry the sets should be disjoint. However your solution is what I meant by brute force - it really doesn't scale.

Comment: @dbc Its not really a Fixed-radius NNS as it is usually defined, since we need we don't query on a point but a set of them. The domain is 3D euclidean space - sorry, should've specified.

Comment: I see that you accepted a solution.  Any interest in a solution that uses the Fixed-radius near neighbors algorithm?  A quick test shows that, given 1 million points total (in and out of the set), it finds all points within a given distance in, say, 20 seconds, without much optimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To choose a candidate for S2 uniformly at random: choose p in S1 uniformly at random, choose q such that d(p, q) ≤ r uniformly at random, count the number k of points p' (including p) such that d(p', q) ≤ r, and return q with probability 1/k, else start over from the beginning. The expected running time is worst-case quadratic.

Comment: This sounds magical. I'm going to try it out tomorrow and I'll accept your answer if it works.